# WCF service suddenly refuses to start in VS2017 debug

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service which has been running for years, with frequent updates/additions from me. I usually test the service from within VS before deploying to production server. I recently tried to add a new endpoint, like this (DeliveryReport), interface and implementation:

```
[ServiceContract (Namespace = "carsweb.no/")]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string DeliveryReport(string s);

        //[OperationContract]
        //string GetData(string value); several here....

  public class Verksted : IService1
    {
        public string DeliveryReport(string rep)
        {
            return "You posted " + rep;
        }
```

Then the WCF Test client in VS refused to add the service and gave me this message:
"Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata."
I then commented out ALL my changes (not very much), and likewise removed a reference to 'ServiceModel.Web' which I had to add. But I still get the same error when starting the WCF Test Client although everything is as before. There were no changes made to the config (I've checked). Config is the same before and after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
  <configSections>
      <section name="CarsGlobalService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LogFolder" value="C:\usr\INF05\TMP\"/>
    <add key="ConfigFolder" value="c:\CarsGlobal\Config\"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommissionFacade" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="MedlemServiceSoap">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="dbsBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap"/>
        <binding name="ApplicationWebService" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="emsPortBinding"/>
        <binding name="VerkstedSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint Several endpoints in here which all works well"/>
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="CarsGlobalService.Verksted">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/CarsGlobalService/Verksted/mex"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CarsGlobalService.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Complete message from WCF client is

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/CarsGlobalService/Verksted/mex?wsdl If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  
For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    
URI: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/CarsGlobalService/Verksted/mex?wsdl    
Metadata contains a reference which cannot be resolved: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/CarsGlobalService/Verksted/mex?wsdl.    
No endpoints listening on http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/CarsGlobalService/Verksted/mex?wsdl, som kunne godta meldingen. Dette skyldes ofte en feil adresse eller SOAP-handling. Se InnerException, hvis tilgjengelig, hvis du vil ha flere detaljer.    
Cannot connect to the external server.   
Cannot connect because the computer refused connection on 127.0.0.1:8733HTTP GET Error    
URI: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/CarsGlobalService/Verksted/mex?wsdl    
Error occurred during downloading of http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/CarsGlobalService/Verksted/mex?wsdl.    
Cannot connect to the external server    Cannot connect because the target computer refused connection 127.0.0.1:8733
```

I tried to make some other WCF service a couple of days ago, and I got the same message.
Is it something with the network, my computer, my VS environment or what? I am completely stuck!

Comment: Service baseAddress contains mex endpoint address. Did you try using different baseAddress than what you are having currently?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the config, it's all the same as before. I tend to think there is something with my computer or VS environment. Unless someone can give me a good reason...

Comment: Could be firewall. If firewall is enabled then you can allow port 8733.